# browse to button MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am using a desktop database. I want to add browse to button

the function will be i will select a file from the filebrowser and if I select that picture or any file and it will show in the Text Box that I created the location of the file.

I am using this code but I am having an error using it.

```
Private Sub cmdBrowseTo_Click()
Dim fdg As FileDialog, vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strSelectedFile As String
Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fdg
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
If .Show = -1 Then
For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
strSelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
Next vrtSelectedItem
Me![Path] = strSelectedFile
Else
End If
End With
Set fdg = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error is

*Compile error:
User-defined type not defined*

Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: At last it works. Big tip check your Reference in the tool and change some commands in this vb

Answer (score 0):

Please add reference to Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library (Tools->References in VBA Editor)